# how to add numeric value to for loop

Tags: javascript

i have pass numeric value to javascript function.i want to check it in for loop.val is amount of checkboxes.in this thime there is two checkboxes.then val is 2

```
function cal(val, id){ // val =2
    var sum = 0;
    var gn, elem;
    var l = 1 * val; //l=1*2
    var b = parseInt(l) + 1; // b=2+1
    for (i = 1; i < b; i++) { //this is not working.but b to replace 3,it's working
        alert(i);
        gn = 'testw' + i; //checkboxes ids
        elem = document.getElementById(gn);
        if (elem.checked == true) {
            sum += Number(elem.value); //calculate checkboxes values
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("rp").value = sum.toFixed(2);
    // display total in textfield
}
```

Comment: How are you saying that it didn't work in the for loop?

Comment: for (i=1; i<=c; i++)

Comment: Saying something didn't work isn't helpful. What precisely did you expect? What precisely happened?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me:http://jsfiddle.net/m4705xj7/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/wxx01p37/